# Как мне вернуть значение через указатель?

Tags: c++

```
bool* condition(int* x, int* y) {
return (x > y) && (y % 2 == 0);
}

bool** Ratio(int** arr) {
bool **matrix = new bool*[N];
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    matrix[i] = new bool[N];
}
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        matrix[i][j] = condition(arr[i], arr[j]);
    }
}
return matrix;
}
```

Выдает ошибку,что y не относится к целочисленному типу или другому типу.
Суть задачи: проверить два числа на условие и вернуть значение в матрицу 1 или 0.

Comment: Скажите только одно - ЗАЧЕМ???? И что вы хотите передавать В функцию?

Comment: Функции в с++ не могут возвращать массивы

Comment: а вы  любите все делать указательями?...

Comment: @Harry Я хочу передать туда два значения и вернуть значение проверки условия и записать в матрицу 1 или 0.Можно конечно делать векторами,но это неудобно.

Comment: @Bogdan Bida Могут,у меня все работает.

Comment: Хотя в вашем случае это все таки указатель а не сам массив. Так что да

Comment: Мне кажется, что в `condition()` вы хотите все же сравнивать не указатели (адреса), а значения по этим адресам.

Comment: @avp Верно,как мне это сделать?

Comment: @Владислав Молодожонов,  что работает?

Comment: Разыменовать указатели (писать `*x`, `*y`).

Answer (score 2):

```
 bool condition(int* x, int* y) {
return (*x > *y) && (*y % 2 == 0);
}
```

это для избавления от ошибки компиляции, но не избавит вас от логически неправильного кода
 Да, еще откуда взялась N в функции?

Comment: Глобальная переменная const int N.

Comment: размер нужно передавать как аргумент функции  или как шаблон,  а глобальных переменных старайтесь избегать

Answer (score 0):

Как можно тип bool проверить на деление (bool % 2)? Нужно пересмотреть условие проверки.